# I have a 135' run to my boat lift

Tags: electrical

I have to run 135'power cord from my cabin to my boat lift and my 2 boat battery chargers will also run off this.  I was told to make my own cord using 10/3 SJOOW wire so I don't have an issue with voltage drop.  This is on a 15 amp 125 V GFCI outdoor outlet so I need a standard male plug.  My question is I can't seem to find a male end that will handle the larger 10/3 wire.  I see all kinds that will handle 12/3 but nothing larger.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Eh, is this a temporary cord or are you putting it in place and forgetting about it?

Answer (score 1):

For a temporary cord cap you are probably going to have to use an industrial grade cord cap. Leviton -  black & white lists #10 AWG with cord sizes up to .700" (strain relief insert removed for the larger size). Part #'s 5269-C & 5266-C. This is not an endorsement I just happen to have some on the shelf. Be prepared for a bit of sticker shock compared to non Specification / industrial grade cord caps. Hubble also makes one almost exactly the same. These are the 2 brands I normally use.